# How does a kernel return from the thread

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system, kernel, bootloader

I am doing some study hardcore study on computers etc. so I can get started on my own mini Hello World OS.

I was looking a how kernels work and I was wondering how the kernel makes the current thread return to the kernel (so it can switch to another) even though the kernel isn't running and the thread has no instruction to do so.

Does it use some kind of CPU interrupt that goes back to the kernel after a few nanoseconds?

Comment: http://wiki.osdev.org/Multitasking_Systems

Comment: Frankly, I don't think anyone would have guessed you didn't have any programming experience until you mentioned "without programming experience"—the fact that you mentioned it just makes you sound insecure!

Comment: I just said that because on tonnes of other sites I have went to always mentioned stuff like "you need programming experience". But thanks for the feedback, I am new to this site and didn't really think that people would assume I knew programming...

Comment: Without necessary prior reading and research, such questions usually create more questions and it becomes a boring and tiresome process for both parties and becomes much less effective than reading. For that, it's a good idea to clarify concepts with a little research. Here is a nice article about that: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0):

> Does it use some kind of CPU interrupt that goes back to the kernel after a few nanoseconds?

It is during timer interrupts and (blocking) system calls that the kernel decides whether to keep executing the currently active thread(s) or switch to another thread. The timer interupt handler updates resource usages, such as consumed system and user time, for the currently running process and `scheduler_tick()` function that decides whether a process/tread need to be pre-empted.

See "Preemption and Context Switching" on page 62 of [Linux Kernel Development book](http://stid.googlecode.com/files/Linux.Kernel.Development.3rd.Edition.pdf).

> The kernel, however, must know when to call schedule(). If it called schedule() only
>   when code explicitly did so, user-space programs could run indefinitely. Instead, the kernel
>   provides the need_resched flag to signify whether a reschedule should be performed (see
>   Table 4.1).This flag is set by scheduler_tick() when a process should be preempted, and
>   by try_to_wake_up() when a process that has a higher priority than the currently run-
>   ning process is awakened.The kernel checks the flag, sees that it is set, and calls schedule() to switch to a new process.The flag is a message to the kernel that the scheduler should be invoked as soon as possible because another process deserves to run.

Comment: 'It is during timer interrupts'. What about all the other I/O hardware interrupts that are absolutely essential? Why are so many developers fixated on the timer interrupt?

Comment: Probably because one can set a timer for a time when the current process time slice expires. Checking whether a process needs to be pre-empted on any/every other interrupt may cause kernel doing more unnecessary work.

Comment: The driver is quite capable of working out whether it needs to make a thread ready or not and, if it does to set the necesary signals and exit via the scheduler so that waiting threads are made ready. 99.99% of threads never get near any 'time slice' scheduling decision - their job is over long before then.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it use some kind of CPU interrupt

**Yes!**  Modern preemptive kernels are absolutely dependent upon interrupts from hardware to deliver good I/O performance.  Keyboard, mouse, disk, NIC, USB, etc. drivers are all entered from interrupts and can make threads that are waiting on them ready/running when required (e.g., when data is available).

Threads can also change state as a result of making an OS call that changes the caller's own state of that of another thread.

The interrupt from the hardware timer is one of many interrupt sources and is only special in that many system operations have timeouts that are signaled by this interrupt.  Other than that, the timer interrupt just causes a reschedule which, in most cases, changes nothing re. the ready/running state of threads.  If the machine is grossly CPU-overloaded to the point where there are more ready threads than there are cores, there is a side-effect of the timer interrupt that causes CPU time to be shared amongst the ready threads.

Do not fixate on the timer interrupt—the other driver interrupts are absolutely essential.  It is not impossible to build a functional preemptive multithreaded kernel with no timer interrupt  at all.

Comment: Which other interrupts besides the timer are aboslutely always there, have controllable or at least predictable rate of occurence, do not depend on external factors (like user input or network activity) and servicing them is not time-critical?